# Connecting to your RDS DB Instance

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-rds

Hi after connecting to my RDS DB instance, how do I connect to it via Eclipse and create tables on my database (using Java code not Eclipse API).

```
CreateDBInstanceRequest createDBInstanceRequest = new CreateDBInstanceRequest()
        .withEngine("MySQL")
        .withLicenseModel("general-public-license")
        .withEngineVersion("5.6.13")
        .withDBInstanceClass("db.t1.micro")
        .withMultiAZ(false)
        .withAutoMinorVersionUpgrade(true)
        .withAllocatedStorage(5)
        .withDBInstanceIdentifier("mydbinstance")
        .withMasterUsername("master")
        .withMasterUserPassword("password")
        .withDBName("dbname")
        .withPort(3306);

        DBInstance dbInstance = rds.createDBInstance(createDBInstanceRequest);

        DescribeDBInstancesRequest instRequest = new DescribeDBInstancesRequest();
        DescribeDBInstancesResult instResult = new DescribeDBInstancesResult();
        Endpoint e = dbInstance.getEndpoint();
```

Do I need to download mySQL connector?

Answer (score 0):

You might try this guide that shows you how to connect to the instance with Eclipse once it has been instantiated - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSToolkitEclipse/latest/GettingStartedGuide/tke_rds.html